# Mute HTTP headers with openssl s_client

Tags: bash, automation, openssl

I have a one line bash command which gets me an HTML site over an SSL encrypted HTTPS connection:

`echo "GET / HTTP/1.1\nHost: www.example.com\n\n" | openssl s_client -connect www.example.com:443 -quiet 2> /dev/null`

The site is being loaded but with HTTP headers like:

> HTTP/1.1 200 OK
>   Date: Fri, 01 Feb 2013 13:15:59 GMT
>   Server: Apache/2.2.20 (Ubuntu)

and more like this. With `2> /dev/null` I can hide the output of wrong SSL certificates and more.
I do not want to take another script because curl does not what I want to do.

Comment: why not `wget https://example.com` instead?

Comment: I want to create a script which asks a user for some input and then passes it via pipe to openssl s_client which connects securely to a web server with HTTPS.  
I believe that it does not work for my case because `openssl s_client -connect something:someport` just gives the direct output from the service which serves behind the specific port (like apache on 443 or 80).

Comment: Oh and `telnet` is not possible because I do not want to manually encrypt the whole traffic, would be too complicated or nearly impossible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible due to the nature of `openssl s_client` which gives you the direct and plain output from a service which runs behind the connecting port (443 in my example from the question where I want to get / on a webserver with SSL).

`telnet` would also give you the plain output from the HTTP protocol and `curl` would show me the HTML site without headers and with HTTPS but does not allow self written commands to the web server.

Answer (score 0):

You may use expect command to do the interaction with openssl. I'm not sure it will work but it worth a try.